# Cannot install windows, missing device driver

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, drivers

I am having Sony vaio VPCM126AG, which was running windows 10 pro.

I tried to install chromium os hdd will had wiped full hdd, then chromium os was running well, but now I wanted to go back to windows.

Since the laptop do not have CD drive, usb is the only option.

When installation came to hdd partition selection, it was't showing any partition.

I used diskpart command line and formatted partition with NTFS format, but I think the problem is different.

See the attached pictures..
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try reformatting your USB and putting the Windows you want to boot on it again.  I know this usually occurs when the media is currupted. Mostly with the ISO file if it happens again try and get another copy of the OS

Comment: I tried couple of times. I have win 10 32 bit & 64 bit for pro, and 64 bit for win 10 home. Also tried window 8 32 bit. Usually all of these iso works and this time all failed. I think the problem with usb pen drive. I used universal installer and also tried rufus tool to create usb bootable. Suddenly it isn't showing in widows explorer. However ubs tools are showing the usb drive. Even mobile detects it very well

Comment: Do you have another USB drive to try out?

Comment: I don't have another USB except backup drive. I think this time it should work. I used chrome recovery utility to remove any recovery and boot info and formatted it. Though it wasn't showing in explorer. I thought lets use diskpart to assign letter and now it shows in explorer. I am again trying to make windows usb installer and will see if it works. Hoping this time it should work

Comment: glad you got it going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out that when I used chrome recovery utility to install chromium os, it must have changed my pen partition. Later when I format it with usb tools like rufus and universal installer, and also bootice as well, but none were able to show my pen drive on explorer. I was about to download window 7 usb creator tool but I again Googled and some one told that use the chrome recovery utility again to remove recovery information and format the drive. Once I used it, I just used diskpart again to assign letter and it was showing on explorer. Then I again created windows 10 usb installer and this time it worked. Thanks @NetworkKingPin to give me hint about pen drive issue